# How to solve the error "Failed to launch Terminal" after upgrading python?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, python, gnome-terminal

How to solve the error "failed to launch Terminal" failed to execute child process￼ GNOME-Terminal ( No such file or directory ) ? Please HELP us to solve this error. Currently I have upgraded Python to 3.7 version.

I have tried opening by clicking Alt+F2 and entered "gnome-terminal" but that too failed.

I tried "`sudo apt-get purge gnome-terminal`" in a shell opened on clicking "Ctrl + Alt + F3" keys which removed my terminal from the system

And then ran "`sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`", I got terminal back but with the same error.

Comment: It sounds like you might have accidentally uninstalled `gnome-terminal`.  Have you tried typing `xterm` into the Alt+F2 box instead?

Comment: I tried to open Xterm but in vain. Xterm itself not opening.

Comment: Can you get to a console with CTRL+ALT+F3 or F4?    Once in the console, log in and type `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` which will reinstall all the required packages.  Then you can get back to the GUI with CTRL+ALT+F1 or F2.

Comment: Did it and same problem continues

Comment: What if you tried typing `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` into the ALT-F2 box instead?  It could be a profile path issue.

Comment: Please state what you did to solve it so it can help others.  You should be able to answer the question yourself below. :-)

Comment: post as answer @tudor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts,

I found the cause of issue. Python upgraded to version 3.7 and lost its version 3.5

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

Above command installed python 3.5 which is used to run terminal by Ubuntu 18.04 by default.

> Note:
>
> Uninstalling Python 3.5 causes removal of terminal, desktop, firefox
> and some applications in Ubuntu.
>
> **Better don't do it.**

Carefully upgrade/install python versions.

Answer (score 2):

The gnome-terminal requires python 3.5. The highest probability is that you could have messed with python 3.5 which comes readily installed with Ubuntu 18.04. You can check your default python version using

```
python --version
```

If python3.5 not listed here you can check

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

If its still not among the list then install it from [this link](https://vlearningit.wordpress.com/install-python3-5-from-the-source-in-ubuntu-18-04/)

In case python 3.5 is installed in your system, you would want to reinstall it.

Lastly if you still cannot open the terminal try reinstalling gnome-terminal like this

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```