# mucking around with python and gnome-terminal will not launch

Tags: command-line, python, gnome-terminal, python3

I am running 20.04.3 and tried to upgrade my python environment and horked something.

The terminal will not launch. Thankfully, I kept my Mac Book after I switched my main dev work to this new Ubuntu system.

I have tried the workarounds listed, for example, here:

[How to solve the error "Failed to launch Terminal" after upgrading python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083411/how-to-solve-the-error-failed-to-launch-terminal-after-upgrading-python)

But when I try to launch gnome-terminal in the desktop, it fails silently. But in /var/log/syslog, I see:

```
Mar 25 16:50:14 ray0 systemd[1284]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Mar 25 16:50:14 ray0 gnome-shell[36936]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 25 16:50:14 ray0 gnome-shell[36936]:   File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
Mar 25 16:50:14 ray0 gnome-shell[36936]:     from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
Mar 25 16:50:14 ray0 gnome-shell[36936]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
Mar 25 16:50:14 ray0 systemd[1284]: gnome-launched-org.gnome.Terminal.desktop-36936.scope: Succeeded.
```

There might be other problems. For example:

```
# lsb_release -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

But I am having problems getting a bootable install disk created. I can ssh into the machine from another machine and run things on the CLI.

Is there are way to repair the system in general and the terminal specifically?

Comment: It’s generally not a good idea to “muck around with Python” on most Linux-based systems. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/384041/1222991) from a few years ago may help.

Comment: I know that __now__.  :--)

Comment: So, none of the suggested fixes did anything. Same error.

Comment: Sounds like an opportune reason to reinstall the OS, then 

Comment: I eventually had to make a complete backup of my data and re-install the operating system. One should be able to fix the python environment, or the python environment that the OS uses should not have anything to do with the user-visible python environment.One wonders, why does the OS-required python not use a protected virtualenv? Unless I misunderstand, it seems that this would work.